# StaticLabelsFormatter and setXAxisBoundsManual issue in Graphview

Tags: android, android-graphview

I am using Graphview in Android. Inside my graph, I am showing bargraph with some custom static labels.

If I am not manually adjusting the Xbounds, then static labels show up , but they are not placed at the middle of bar. Also the bars don't have proper spacing.

```
series.resetData(graphDataPoints.toArray(new GraphDataPoint[graphDataPoints.size()]));
StaticLabelsFormatter mLabelsFormatter = new StaticLabelsFormatter(graph);
mLabelsFormatter.setHorizontalLabels(horizontalLabels.toArray(new String[horizontalLabels.size()]));
mGridLabelRenderer.setLabelFormatter(mLabelsFormatter);
```

If I manually adjust Xbounds, then bars show up nicely, but the static labels are distorted. In my case one label doesn't show up.

```
series.resetData(graphDataPoints.toArray(new GraphDataPoint[graphDataPoints.size()]));
graph.getViewport().setXAxisBoundsManual(true);
graph.getViewport().setMinX(series.getLowestValueX() -0.5);
graph.getViewport().setMaxX(series.getHighestValueX() +0.5);
StaticLabelsFormatter mLabelsFormatter = new StaticLabelsFormatter(graph);
mLabelsFormatter.setHorizontalLabels(horizontalLabels.toArray(new String[horizontalLabels.size()]));
mGridLabelRenderer.setLabelFormatter(mLabelsFormatter);
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was that I created the `DataPoints` as `DataPoint(i+1,y)`, so there was an offset in the horizontal direction. Then I put `minX` to `0` and `maxX` to `NBRBARS+1` so that you could see everything of the bars.

To compensate for the labels I had to add one space `" "` on each side of the array, i.e. `String labels[] = {" ", "label 1", "label 2", " "}`.